# Let $f(x)=x^3-6x^2+x+4$ and $g(x)=x^5-6x+1\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Use extended euclidean algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

Let $f(x)=x^3-6x^2+x+4$ and  $g(x)=x^5-6x+1\in  \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Find $\gcd(f,g)$ by using the Euclidean algorithm.(done)

Also use extended euclidean algorithm to  find $s(x),t(x) \in Q[x]$ s.t. $\gcd(f,g)=fs+gt$. (not done)

---

Note that we are in $Q[x]$ land. 
$$\begin{aligned} 
  x^5-6x+1 & =(x^3-6x^2+x+4)(x^2+6x+35)+(200x^2-65x-139) \\
   x^3-6x^2+x+4 & =(200x^2-65x-139)\left (\frac{x}{200}-\frac{227}{8000} \right)
                        + \left (\frac{239}{1600}x+\frac{447}{8000} \right) \\
  200x^2-65x-139 &=\left( \frac{-239}{1600}x+\frac{447}{8000} \right)  \left (\frac{-3200}{239}x-\frac{375200}{57121}\right )+\frac{-7731076}{57121}
\end{aligned}$$
 So $\gcd(f(x),g(x))=1$

Setting up for reveres substitution

$$\begin{aligned} 
 \frac{-7730176}{57121}& =(200x^2-65x-139)
          - \left (\frac{-239}{1600}x+\frac{447}{800} \right)
               \left ( \frac{-320000}{239}x-\frac{375200}{57121} \right)      \\
 \frac{-239x}{1600} +\frac{447}{8000}
        &= \left ( x^3-6x^2+x+4  \right)     -\left ( \left (200x^2-65x -139 \right)                                        \left ( \frac{x}{200}-\frac{227}{8000}\right)  \right) \\
200x^2-65x-139&= \left (\left (x^5-6x+1 \right )
                   -\left(x^3-6x^2+x+4\right)\left (x^2+6x+35 \right)\right)
                   \end{aligned} $$
Call them 1,2,3 in decending order where 1 is constant=____

$3 \to 2$

$$ \frac{-239x}{1600} +\frac{447}{8000}
        = \left ( x^3-6x^2+x+4  \right)     -\left ( \left (\left (x^5-6x+1 \right )
                   -\left(x^3-6x^2+x+4\right)\left (x^2+6x+35 \right)\right)                                        \left ( \frac{x}{200}-\frac{227}{8000}\right)  \right)   $$

*Running out of real state at this point* but missing a step got 
$$\frac{-239x}{1600} +\frac{447}{8000}
        =(x^3-6x^2+x+4)\left (1-\left (x^2+6x+35\right) \left(\frac{x}{200}-\frac{227}{8000} \right) \right)
                      -\left( x^5-6x+1 \right) \left (\frac{x}{200}-\frac{227}{8000}\right) $$

$2 \to 1$

$\frac{-7730176}{57121}=(200x^2-65x-139)
                       - \left ( (x^3-6x^2+x+4)(1-(x^2+6x+35)(\frac{x}{200}-\frac{337}{800}))(\frac{-340000x}{239})-\frac{375,200}{571221} \right)
+ (-1)(x^5-6x+1)(\frac{x}{200}-\frac{227}{8000})(\frac{-320000x}{239}-\frac{375200}{57121}) $

---

Was able find the gcd but could no find the $sf+tg=1$

Comment: note that there is a similar problem but it did not back substitute or actually used euclidean algorithm just "justified it"  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522030/justify-gcd-of-fx-x3-6x2-x-4-and-gx-x5-6x-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialExtendedGCD%5Bx%5E3-6x%5E2%2Bx%2B4%2C+x%5E5-6x%2B1%5D) is really horrible:

$
s=\dfrac1{120784}(-5975 x^4-2235 x^3-4879 x^2-3139 x+30835)
$

$
t=\dfrac1{120784}(5975 x^2-33615 x-2556)
$

No wonder you're having trouble!